# ASP.NET Core: static files protected are not accessible at all

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0

Using ASP.NET Core 6.0, I am developing an application which uses documents like images (JPG, PNG) and documents (PDF). I am trying to protect those files in the folder outside the `wwwroot` (static/images, static/documents).

The code (`program.cs`) is:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions { ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All });
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseMiddleware<StaticFileAuthorizationMiddleware>();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(app.Environment.ContentRootPath, "static")),
    RequestPath = "/static",
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        if (!ctx.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ctx.Context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            ctx.Context.Response.ContentLength = 0;
            ctx.Context.Response.Body = Stream.Null;
        }
    }
});
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Documents are protected, but the app also cannot access (status 401). Please help :)

Any advise would be very welcome.

Comment: What do you mean about `but the app also cannot access`? Even you logged in, you can also access the static files? I test your code and it works well.

Comment: Even if logged, the current user also get status 401 - obviously OnPrepareResponse is called before UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization (although order in code)

Comment: The order of middlewares are correct, I am not sure if this `app.UseMiddleware<StaticFileAuthorizationMiddleware>();` middleware affect the result.